# django: adding custom permissions stopped working

Tags: django, migration

I have a django project with multiple apps. In one of the apps when I add custom permissions to any model and run makemigration, the migration-file to add the permission is created. When I apply the migration I get no error messages but the permission isn't added to the auth_permission table.

```
class Meta:
    app_label = 'my_app'

    permissions = (
        ('assign_work_type', 'Assign work type'),
    )
```

The migration completes without errors

[image]

I have tried doing the same in other apps and that works. I have also tried adding a column to the current app and that works as well. Anyone got any idea what it could be? I am running django 1.11.26

**UPDATE**

Here is the content of the migration file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.11.26 on 2019-11-25 11:13
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('timereport', '0143_auto_20191122_1754'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterModelOptions(
            name='worktype',
            options={'permissions': (('assign_work_type', 'Assign work type'),)},
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Please add the error to your question.

Comment: There is no error message. It completes with "OK"

Comment: could you show the content inside the migration file ?

Comment: Added the migration file to the post

Comment: that's is wired the only way I noticed this kind of problem is when you have not registered your app in the INSTALLED_APPS in this case `my_app`, check with the output of this query `SELECT * FROM 'auth_permission' where codename='assign_work_type'`  and check that this is not blank

Comment: Thank you. That is the weird thing, it isn't added. This is a 5 year old project and has been working fine until now. It is so strange

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: Version 1.11.26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite some investigation I found that the affected app was missing the models_module, i.e. the "models.py" file. I have all my models in a /model/ directory and a while back I deleted the models.py file thinking it was of no use.

Adding the models.py file back solved the issue