# Django Custom Permissions not synced to DB

Tags: django, python-3.x, permissions, customization

I am newbie to Python and Django. I am trying to addd custom permissions using Django documentation. I added new permissions to model meta data.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        permissions = [
            ("create_project", "Can create project"),
            ("update_project", "Can update project"),
            ("view_project", "Can view project")
        ]
```

Then I ran

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations [app_name]
```

and output was

```
app/migrations/0009_auto_20191209_1848.py 
- Change Meta options on project
```

Then I ran

```
python3 manage.py migrate [app_name]
```

and output was

```
Applying app.0009_auto_20191209_1848... OK
```

But I do not see new permission added to **auth_permission**.

I tried `--run-syncdb` option but that did not work as well.

What I am doing wrong and how I can debug this issue?

thanks,

UPDATE:

content of **0009_auto_20191209_1848.py**

```
# Generated by Django 2.2.6 on 2019-12-09 18:48

from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app', '0008_auto_20191209_1817'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterModelOptions(
            name='project',
            options={'permissions': [('create_project', 'Can Create Project'), ('update_project', 'Can Create Project'), ('view_project', 'Can View Project')]},
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of 0009_auto_20191209_1848.py?

Comment: @DanielRoseman just updated my post with content of 0009_auto_20191209_1848.py thanks

Comment: @Zeedia are you definitely running the migration against and checking the same DB?

Comment: @IainShelvington yes, and to be sure I just dropped all custom db tables for custom models and re-migrate everything. I can see custom tables got created but not it did not add any new permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on [Adding Custom Permissions Stopped Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59007757/django-adding-custom-permissions-stopped-working)
I was missing `models.py` on my app adding that file fixed the problem.